# Pretty url index page

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I only got the **first** pretty url working. I don't get the 2nd and 3rd working, they just show a messed up page (Styles not loaded) + it show wrong page

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?tab=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^/ucp(.*)$ index.php?ucp&tab=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^/ucp(.*)$ index.php?ucp [NC,L]
```

.

```
Possible urls:
http://subdomain.domain.com/path2files/index.php?&tab=str
http://subdomain.domain.com/path2files/index.php?ucp
http://subdomain.domain.com/path2files/index.php?ucp&tab=str

How they should look like:
http://subdomain.domain.com/path2files/str
http://subdomain.domain.com/path2files/ucp
http://subdomain.domain.com/path2files/ucp/str
```

Comment: So what's wrong? You keep editing stuff in/out of your question?

Comment: Sorry. I had some problems editing this :(
I have made the final edit now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /path2files/index\.php\?ucp&tab=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /path2files/ucp/%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^path2files/ucp/(.*)$ /path2files/index.php?ucp&tab=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /path2files/index\.php\?ucp\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /path2files/ucp\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^path2files/ucp$ /path2files/index.php?ucp [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /path2files/index\.php\?&tab=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /path2files/%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ucp
RewriteRule ^path2files/(.*)$ /path2files/index.php?&tab=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Whenever I add an extra **/** like after the **tab_name**, the page looks messy (No css)

And the **.../ucp/tab_name** show a messy page, with or without an **/** at the very end.